# How to move Sonar database to another host?

Tags: sonarqube

I export my Sonar database (Oracle) and import it into another Oracle database. And I change my Sonar's sonar.properties to the new host. But when I start Sonar, it try to create the table and because these tables are already on the database server, I cannot start Sonar.

Is there any configuration I should set for this change? The change reason is the old database is too small and we want to change to larger database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the SonarQube server tries to recreate the tables when using the new host that might mean that the content of the schema_migrations table has been incorrectly migrated.

Comment: Thanks, I found this table is empty in my new database and I copy it from the old db to the new one and it's ok now. But I'll try to re-export again and check why I lost the table.